# Erro ao tentar atualizar as Fields do ClientDataSet no Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, postgresql, delphi-7, tclientdataset

Estou migrando uma aplicação do `Delphi 7` que antes era em `FireBird` e agora estou conectando ao banco `PostgreSQL`, porém estava ocorrendo um erro de variáveis, com a ajuda do pessoal do Stack, descobri que poderia ser as `Fields` do `ClientDataSet` que poderiam ter que ser atualizadas para que não ocorre mais o erro. Consegui fazer isso com a `dmCadEmpresas`, porém quando tento em todas as outras `Fields` está ocorrendo o erro a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei e não encontrei o que poderia estar ocasionando isso, se tiverem alguma idéia

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada se a sua aplicação contém o midas.dll dentro da pasta do projeto, pois o clientdataset necessita dessa dll para poder funcionar, ou senão, declara no uses da classe o MIdasLib.

Comment: Conferi e o midas.dll esta dentro da pasta do meu projeto

Comment: Com relação ao midas, melhor é declarar no dpr uses MidasLib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo que você restaure um Backup desse projeto e refaça o que lhe informei na outra pergunta!

[Para essa:](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/erro-ao-instalar-componente/181301)

> O pacote DesignIDE (DesignIDE70.bpl na subpasta ´bin´ e DesignIDE.dcp
>   na subpasta ´lib´) serve apenas para ser utilizado na IDE do Delphi
>   7.0 e não nas aplicações finais. Por isso, você não deve acrescentá-lo em seus projetos finais e nem em seus pacotes de componentes.